# Format currency based on condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to Google Apps Script, but have some VBA coding experience.

I am looking to be able to have the numeric format of a cell decided based on a different cell input.

eg.

- Col A - Client Name (Validated range)
- Col B - Currency Type (GBP, USD, EUR - validated list)
- Col C - Fee  (100 - free type by user)

Based on the selection in Col B it needs to put the format in col C as either:

£100.00 or
$100.00 or
€100.00.

This should be done in such a way that the "autosum" function displayed on the bottom of google sheet is still able to add the values, or if using a sumif function will result in the USD, GBP and EUR totals being correct. I.E.  it cannot be a text based solution or at least not one where this is not the result.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask]. If you decided to edit your question, please describe why and how do you expect this be solved through [tag:google-apps-script] instead of using built-in number format / locale settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), and set custom number format.

Here's code sampe for currency formats:

```
function customNumberFormat() {

  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var range1 = ss.getRange("C2");
  var range2 = ss.getRange("C3");
  var range3 = ss.getRange("C4");

  var format1 = "£ 00.00"
  var format2 = "$ 00.00"
  var format3 = "€ 00.00"

  range1.setNumberFormat(format1);
  range2.setNumberFormat(format2);
  range3.setNumberFormat(format3);

}
```

Make script to check current entry in column with sum and format it in proper currency.

---

But text solution with formula looks better for me:
[image]

This way you are hiding the entries in column with sum, and show text with format. Sums can be used in further formulas.

There's also simple ArrayFormula:
`=ArrayFormula(TEXT(C2,VLOOKUP(OFFSET(B2,,,COUNTA(B2:B)),H:I,2,0)&" 0.00"))`

If you paste it in D2, it'll expand automatically.

Comment: Thanks Max.  Limited usage though B2 will need to be selected GBP and C2 will need to be £00.00.  If B2 is selected as USD the C2 will need to be $00.00.  follow?  Your code just sets specific formats not dynamic ones based on the value in cell B2.

Comment: Yes, of course, my code gives the direction in which you may want to act. Sorry, but I think that your question is very specific case, so I have no time to write the whole code for you. Hope, someone will.